# When to link and when to include?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, cppunit

I was writing a test case for a simple c++ program using CppUnit API.
my program is four files:

- Calc.h : Defines the class with the methods to test
- TestCalc.h/cpp : Defines/impelents the class which tests the methods of Calc
- runTestCalc.cpp: Main function which executes the test.

I installed the CppUnit and it has the files under:

```
/usr/local/include/cppunit and /usr/include/cppunit
```

the libs under /usr/lib :

```
libcppunit-1.13.so.0 
libcppunit.a
libcppunit.so
...
```

The question I have is how to compile this example assuming the proper CppUnit header files are properly included in the sources

I tried this:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/cppunit/ runTestCalc.cpp TestCalc.cpp
```

The other question is when to do

-I/to/include/
-L/to/lib

When to link ?

Comment: You'll need to do both in most cases.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so how do you compile in this case

Comment: Provide all of the compiler/liker flags together?

Answer (score 1):

`c++ runTestCalc.cpp TestCalc.cpp -o runTestCalc -l cppunit`